# Calculate Length of String with Escape Characters/Special Chars/Formatting

Tags: c#, string

I need to be able to read the literal length of a string.

**EXAMPLES:**

- "\t" would be 4.
- "\t foobar" would be 11
- `String.Format("\t {0, -15}", "Hello World")` would be 20.

Writing a decoder would be easy if I only needed it to work for tabs and spaces, but for the third example I'm clueless to how I would do that. Is there any way to force a String to interpret itself in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: For the third example, call `String.Format` with those parameters, and then measure the string with tabs (don't forget that "a\t" and "\t" are *both* four characters, if you're assuming four-space tabs). Of course in that branch, the tabs you're looking for will be the actual tab character instead of a backslash followed by a lowercase "t". The alternative is to reimplement `String.Format`, which is insane. The "way to force a string to interpret itself" is `String.Format`.

Comment: The length of `\t` is always 1.  It only becomes a different apparent length if a particular program is outputting it to a display.  For example, NotePad uses 8 columns for a tab; LINQPad uses 3; Visual Studio uses 4; and Microsoft Word uses 0.5 *inches*.  So the question is what display are you targeting for your calculation of the effective length?  If the Tab character is the only thing you're concerned about (and it's always at the beginning, and under the assumption of a 4-character tab), a simple solution would be `"the string".Replace("\t", "    ").Length`.

Comment: The Command Prompt is the display I am using. And I think one tab = 4 spaces. I am using String.Replace for my current solution, but was wondering if there is a better way of doing it. My current requirements are just tabs, but there is no guarantee this will not change.

Comment: So what your *real* question is how to emulate output of a program to a Command Prompt window and pre-determine exactly how it would be laid out?

Comment: My question is how to enforce the interpretation of escaped characters to the string that they actually are. so "\t" = "# of tab spaces". Ed already verified that anything you call within String.Format will be interpreted immediately. So, is the only way to swap out escaped characters to run a parser swapping out each one? Or is there a better solution already existing. (I'm willing to do the grunt work, but only if there isn't some better thing out there that I'm oblivious to)

Comment: I think you're fundamentally confusing what a string *is* and how a string is *displayed* by a program.  A string is a collection of characters.  Because it is difficult to correctly type a TAB character in most IDE's, we represent it by the "escape sequence" of `\t`.  But it is underneath character #9 (TAB character), and is always one character.  A string containing a TAB character is a string of length one.  It is purely convention that certain software programs when they encounter character #9 in a string while displaying it to a terminal, they emit four spaces.

Comment: @mellamokb Your right, tab is its own character and the IDE's and programs that write it out print it as a number of spaces. I didn't realize this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to control that "\t" equals 4 spaces, then why don't you replace all "\t" with 4 spaces?

Something like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetLength("\t"));
    Console.WriteLine(GetLength("\t foobar"));
    Console.WriteLine(GetLength(String.Format("\t {0, -15}", "Hello World")));
    Console.WriteLine(GetLength("a\t"));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static int GetLength(string str)
{
    return str.Replace("\t", "    ").Length;
}
```

Results:

```
4
11
20
5
```

Comment: This is similar to what I'm currently using to solve the problem, I'm still curious if something built into the String class, or some C# library that will give you the interpretation (I've been unable to find anything), but if not, then this is just how its done.

Comment: There isn't, because there's no standard saying that `\t` == 4 spaces - it might be more or less or something else entirely.

Comment: I was hoping there might be some default value that would be used, but I think your right, because \t is a variable value, there is no default interpreter for these escape chars.

Comment: The tab character (`\t`) is a **formatting** or **display** character. That is, the operation of it depends **entirely** on the application interpreting it. Yes, Visual Studio and Notepad both use 4-spaces for the tab, but some programmes use 6, some 2, some 1!

Comment: Not sure its a good idea, because in your last test, I think the answer should be 4. Tab tends to be adjustable and not fixed as just 4 characters.